# Identify subscribers(exe or processes) for winlogon

Tags: windows, winapi, win32-process, xperf, wpr

Hi I wanted to debug login delay
I can see eventvwr event like following that took around 50-60 secs to complete.

```
The winlogon notification subscriber <Profiles> finished handling the notification event (2).
```

Not able to make out which is the process/exe that subscribed for this event, so that I can focus to specific process activities in wpr traces.

If I can check some cmd what subscribers registered for winlogon using some tool or cokmmand that will definitely help

Comment: capture a [boot trace and look at Winlogon entries](https://superuser.com/a/1119007/174557) to see what is causing a delay.

Comment: @magicandre1981 got wpr (not boot trace but normal trace, as it was already provisioned VM), analysed most of top processes.
Just wanted to dig some profile import third party tools, not which tool hold login